# Include PDF Files in LaTeX when not using pdflatex

Tags: pdfpages

I want to add a separate pdf file in the appendix of my thesis.  `\includepdf` is not working as I'm not using pdflatex due to constraint of some block diagrams (PStricks package).  I am forced to use ps to dvi to pdf configuration.  Can any one tell me how to include pdf file in this configuration?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

### dvips

Driver `dvips` neither supports the inclusion of PDF files nor the inclusion of multi-page PostScript files. It supports Encapsulated PostScript files, which have one page exactly.

A PDF file can be converted to EPS files, one per page. Example: `foo.pdf` with two pages is converted by `pdftops` (of `xpdf`/`poppler`):

```bash
pdftops -eps -f 1 -l 1 foo.pdf foo1.eps
pdftops -eps -f 2 -l 2 foo.pdf foo2.eps
```

Instead of

```tex
\includepdf[pages=-]{foo}
```

either several `\includepdf` for each page can be used (depending on the options) or `\includepdfmerge`:

```
\documentclass[dvips]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdfmerge{t1.eps,t2.eps}
\end{document}
```

The warning

```
Package pdfpages Warning: Page selections not supported by driver dvips on input line 4.
```

can be ignored as long as the code does not need to select pages (via `pages=...`).

### pdflatex

Package `pst-pdf` supports `pstricks` in pdfLaTeX. It puts the PostScript stuff into a container. The container is compiled via latex/dvips/ps2pdf to PDF and then in the pdflatex run the PDF container is used instead of the PostScript images.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `dvips` can handle postscript but not PDF, and `pdflatex` can handle PDF but not postscript.  This either/or is unlikely to go away.

Therefore, to first order, the two options are to convert your PDF files to postscript and use `dvips` (which is surely possible, but I haven't had to go there, so can't offer more specific advice), or to convert your postscript files to PDF.  The latter is probably a better idea in general, but is complicated by the fact that you're using `pstricks`.

There is a `pdftricks` package, which is intended to provide `pstricks` support for `pdftex`.  That should make it possible for you to convert your existing postscript files to PDF, and start using `pdftricks` with `pdf(la)tex`.

That's probably The Right Thing To Do, long term, but depending on what stage your thesis is at, and how many figures you have that use `pstricks`, it may be infeasible.  I mention it only to raise the possibility, and to doubt that there is a solution which works around the necessity of making a choice one way of the other.  You'd probably be best to re-ask the question on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ with this in mind.